# install_failed_conflicting_provider android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have the following problem now

I have project1, project2 each one is in separate module in android studio, when I run project1 it works without any problem, now I have converted it to library to be able to include it in project2

when try to run project2 I got the following error  `install_failed_conflicting_provider`

can anyone tell me how to solve this problem ??

Comment: do you use a content provider in these projects?

Comment: You have 2+ apps with `<provider>` elements with the same authority string in `android:authorities`. An authority string must be unique per device. In your case, you have one app installed with the authority string, and you are trying to install another app with that string.

Comment: @tyczj no I am not using content provider

Comment: @CommonsWare all what I do in project1 to change apply plugin: 'com.android.application' to apply plugin: 'com.android.library' and comment applicationId and then add it as library dependancy in project2 , and when I try to run project 2 I got the previous issue.

Comment: Your library presumably has a `<provider>` element (in its own manifest or something it is merging from child libraries), and your apps are not overriding it via manifest merger control options.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am not using '<provider>' in any of manifest files used in all modules, and now I add this tag to project2 ,<provider android:authorities="my-package-name"></provider>, to get the following error ,':_project2:processReleaseManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors,

Comment: "I am not using '<provider>' in any of manifest files used in all modules" -- it may be from a third-party library that your library module references. `install_failed_conflicting_provider` only comes from a conflicting `<provider>`. It is not a question of whether you have a conflicting provider, but where it is coming from. Look in `build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml` in each of the apps to see the `<provider>` elements. You can then look at manifest merger reports to try to determine where they are coming from.

Comment: @CommonsWare you are right I found the providers wrote in generated manifest file of both project, but with different android:authorities , each manifest take it is package name as prefix, how can I avoid this problem, the two duplicated providers for (zopim and zendesk) and I do not have access to them.

Comment: Contact the authors of those providers and ask them how to proceed.